# How to use GraphQL flow types

Tags: graphql, flowtype, graphql-js

I'm having difficulty, trying to use `GraphQL` flow types in my project.

For instance I have a class which expect a `GraphQLSchema` instance as a 
constructor parameter. i.e:

```
import type { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

type MyGraphQLConfig = {
  schemaFiles: string,
  resolvers: Object,
  mocks: Object,
  enableMocks: boolean
}

class GraphQL {
  graphQLSchema: GraphQLSchema;
  configs: MyGraphQLConfig;

  constructor(configs: MyGraphQLConfig, graphQLSchema: GraphQLSchema) {
    this.graphQLSchema = null;
    this.configs = configs;
  }

  getSchema() : GraphQLSchema {
    return this.graphQLSchema;
  }
}
```

When I run the `flow check` command on this file I get the following error:

```
  4: import type { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
                                        ^^^^^^^^^ 
  graphql. Required module not found
```

However when looking at the folder `node_modules/graphql/` I can see all the `.flow` files in there.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your .flowconfig to see if you are ignoring /node_modules/* ?

I am able to fix the issue by removing the ignore.  I do, however, have other issues I have been running into.

Comment: uncommenting `node_modules` from `.flowconfig` worked!